# JSF 1.2 get a request scope managed bean in a regular servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets, managed-bean, jsf-1.2

How can I get a managed bean in a pleain servlet with JSF 1.2? 
I tried several solutions like those proposed here [JSF Managed Beans in a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669560/jsf-managed-beans-in-a-servlet) but without success.

I send an XMLHttpRequest from a facelet where the managed bean is well instanciated, but when I tried this:

```
 @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Bean bean = (Bean) req.getAttribute("bean");//null
    Bean bean = (Bean) getServletContext().getAttribute("bean");//null
}
```

Is there a way on JSF 1.2?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @BalusC The displayed view where I send the XHR request is linked to the managedbean I want, which is annoted with richfaces `@KeepAlive`, I thought that since the view is not closed, the managedbean is still alive and present in the servlet context. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BalusC Because in my case I can't. In my view, the user can copy/paste several images and send them to the server, I use plein JavaScript for this task. I would like to set the path of those images to my current managedbean attribute. That is why I would like to get it in my servlet.

Comment: I save the images in the filesystem in `temp` folder, but for other reasons, when the user will validate the form (managed by the managedbean) I should move those images from `temp` to another folder. So I need the managedbean to keep the location of all images present in the `temp` folder.

Comment: When I say `temp` folder it's about a temp folder on the filesystem where the server resides.

Comment: Assuming session scope: `req.getSession(false).getAttribute(beanName)`.